# HTML Tables, how can I use rowspan and colspan to recreate the photo included

Tags: html, html-table

I am having trouble getting my table to recreate this photo. Not worried about the colors and I will delete the names in the cells just needed them for reference.

[border is white but I am using black on mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WDKr.jpg)

Here is what I am getting. I am not sure where I am going wrong. I've tried to get this for the past five hours and am running out of ideas. How can I get this to look like the picture above?

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF9Bu.jpg)

Here is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML Tables</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <table>  
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">1</td>
     <td rowspan="2" colspan="5">2</td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">3</td>
   
     <td rowspan="2" colspan="4">4</td>
     <td>5</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
     
     <td>6</td>   
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>  
 </body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```css
   body{
    font-family: monospace;
      background-color: #ddd;
   }
   table{
    width: 655px;
    height: 381px;
    border: 35px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
   }

   td{
    border: 20px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
   }
```

I know I have an empty  tag in there but when I take it out the table looks even worse.

**UPDATE**
I was able to get it looking pretty close setting the width and height of my cells

[Updated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcLq8.jpg)

Comment: Are you using this table for a page layout or for tabular data? If you're using it for a page layout, you'll want to use divs and other more modern, semantic elements instead of a table.

Comment: No, not for a page or tabular data. I am just trying to recreate the photo using tables.

Comment: You could add CSS classes to your table cells and then size them to look more like the picture using CSS.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Would an encapsulating div be appropriate for the external yellow+white effect?

Comment: I am restricted to using colspan, rowspan attributes for the table, classes, and id's for the colors. But I have the color scheme done. Just working on getting the layout of my cells to match

Comment: I took a better look at the picture you posted. I was originally thinking about White>yellow>white>table, but realised the pic is just yellow>white>table. Since you are already changing the body color, I think I got it.

Comment: Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c6dftvk/50/). As @Bonnie proposed, I am using css for the columns proportions. If this is appropriate for your question I can explain why I changed it this way, an why your empty tag made (some) sense,  but was maybe part of your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. I changed the width and height of my cells but did it in my html as a td attribute. Is it better practice to do this in my stylesheet? But yeah, I am still a little unclear on the empty tag.

Comment: If you could give an explanation that would be much appreciated.